# How can I add a default gateway with the ip command, not the route command?

Tags: networking, centos7

I want to set a default gateway using the `ip route` command, since I'm under the impression that `ip` is newer and preferred. If I'm not mistaken, `ip` is included in a minimal CentOS installation and not `route`.

What's the equivalent of `route add default gw 192.168.1.254 eth0` using `ip route add`?

Answer (score 28):

Try ip route add default via <host> dev <dev>, e.g.:

```
ip route add default via 192.0.2.2 dev eth0
```

Or you can replace the existing default route:

```
ip route replace default via 192.0.2.1 dev eth0
```

Comment: `ip` is such a powerful command, one cannot call him self network administrator without mastering the `ip` command!